# Flash CS5: exported swf does not play [AS 3.0]

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Well I'm really new to this actionscript stuff. Is there anything wrong in the following code? Whenever I export this, the .swf movie doesn't play, it just shows the 1st frame. Is the if() condition even possible in a function?

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

play();
if(currentFrame == 138)
gotoAndStop(138);
pers_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,pers);
function pers (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(161);
    if(currentFrame == 220)
    stop();
}
kent_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,kent);
function kent (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(161);
    if(currentFrame == 205)
    gotoAndPlay(236);
    if(currentFrame == 251)
    stop();
}
lebe_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,lebe);
function lebe (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(161);
    if(currentFrame == 205)
    gotoAndPlay(221);
    if(currentFrame == 235)
    stop();
}
refe_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,refe);
function refe (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(161);
    if(currentFrame == 205)
    gotoAndPlay(252);
    if(currentFrame == 265)
    stop();
}
zuru_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,zuru);
function zuru (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(138)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's one obvious problem in your code:

```
if(currentFrame == 138)
gotoAndStop(138);
```

You need your curly braces:

```
if(currentFrame == 138){
gotoAndStop(138);
}
```

Cheers,
DrakeSwartzy

Answer (score 0):

oh right, thank you. the swf still doesnt work as it's supposed to tho.. :/
any more suggestions?

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).